# Trigger all page lifecycle events from script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page's html stored in a string.
I want to replace the whole html of the displayed page with the html in my string, and then trigger all the page lifecycle events such as document.ready, window.load, etc.

I though about using the filesystem API - writing the html into the file system and then redirecting to it. Not sure if it's workable, though, and it is definitely an overkill.
Is there an easier and cleaner way to get the same result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
$('html').html(new_html_body);
```

Comment: This will not trigger any events

Comment: "*...and then trigger all the page lifecycle events such as document.ready...*" Read the rest of the question